# How do you reverse a CSS animation (or CSS transition) at any point of the animation using vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, css

**Scenario:**

on mouseover event (on hover), animation plays (Say animated image gets bigger). Then, on mouseout event, animation reverses (animated image shrinks seamlessly upon mouse not hovering on image). The animation reverses at any time the mouse exits the image space.

**Constraints:**

- object in HTML file
- animation CSS property (or CSS transition property) in CSS file
- using mouseover and mouseout events on JS in JS file
- using JS eventlistener function in JS file

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `transition` instead of `animation` this is relatively easy:

```css
.hoverme {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: pink;
  transition: height 10s, width 10s;
}

.hoverme:hover {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hoverme">hover me</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Alexander Nied. This is a good answer. I'm curious as to why this works for the transition property but not the animation property? Also, do you have a more complex strategy for using CSS animation? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this,

```css
.hoverme {
  padding: 50px;
  transition: transform .2s;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.hoverme:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<img class="hoverme" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
```